# Is there a difference between a "contribution" and a "positive contribution"?

Tags: meaning, differences

Just wondering if there's actually a difference as I hear them often.

Comment: You are right that contributions tend to be always positive. "positive contribution" would be perhaps slightly redundant, being used to make clear how beneficial it is.

Comment: Consider that "contributing to global warming" is not generally considered to be "positive".

Comment: @Hot Licks ... But also that different members of 'word families' may have widely differing orientations of sense. 'He's scheming again' / 'He came up with a new scheme'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference.

The word "positive" has many meanings.

In the context of the phrase "positive contribution", the most likely meaning is the one given as 3 by the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=positive):

> a. Desirable, admirable, or beneficial: *a woman with many positive qualities; the positive features of this new software.*
>   
> b. Optimistic or constructive: *a positive attitude.*
>   
> c. Not disparaging or malicious: *ran a positive political campaign.*

If you say something like "I don't think that Bailey made any positive contributions to the conversation", it's implied that even if Bailey took part in the conversation (and thus could be said to have "contributed" to it), the contributions were not constructive or not beneficial.